# Site is not responsive and not adjusting to mobile size screen

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have created this design for practice but it is not responsive it is not adjusting to mobile size screen. All the text should go below the image but it is not doing so. I added the text in a separate `div` which has the class attribute `class="col"`. I have used Bootstrap to make it responsive, but it is not working.

Here is the code

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fraunces:opsz,wght@9..144,100;9..144,200;9..144,300;9..144,400;9..144,500;9..144,600;9..144,700;9..144,800;9..144,900&family=Montserrat:wght@100;300;400;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-u1OknCvxWvY5kfmNBILK2hRnQC3Pr17a+RTT6rIHI7NnikvbZlHgTPOOmMi466C8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="small-box">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="product image" width="300px">
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <div class="text">
        <h6>PERFUME</h6>
        <h1>Gabrielle Essence Eau De Parfum</h1>
        <p> A floral, solar and voluptuous interpretation composed by Olivier Polge, Perfumer-Creator for the House of CHANEL.</p>
        <h1 class="price">$149.99</h1>
        <p class="price-tag"><s>$169.99</s></p>
        <button type="button" class="btn button" name="button"> <svg width="15" height="16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path
                d="M14.383 10.388a2.397 2.397 0 0 0-1.518-2.222l1.494-5.593a.8.8 0 0 0-.144-.695.8.8 0 0 0-.631-.28H2.637L2.373.591A.8.8 0 0 0 1.598 0H0v1.598h.983l1.982 7.4a.8.8 0 0 0 .799.59h8.222a.8.8 0 0 1 0 1.599H1.598a.8.8 0 1 0 0 1.598h.943a2.397 2.397 0 1 0 4.507 0h1.885a2.397 2.397 0 1 0 4.331-.376 2.397 2.397 0 0 0 1.12-2.021ZM11.26 7.99H4.395L3.068 3.196h9.477L11.26 7.991Zm-6.465 6.392a.8.8 0 1 1 0-1.598.8.8 0 0 1 0 1.598Zm6.393 0a.8.8 0 1 1 0-1.598.8.8 0 0 1 0 1.598Z"
                fill="#FFF" />
            </svg>
            <b>Add to Cart</b></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` tag?

Comment: The page behaves as your desired outcome was described--the text is below the image on mobile. Please revise to be more clear about the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you must put the script tag inside of the body element. Then
revising your class with `col-12 col-md-6`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <!-- google fonts -->

  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fraunces:opsz,wght@9..144,100;9..144,200;9..144,300;9..144,400;9..144,500;9..144,600;9..144,700;9..144,800;9..144,900&family=Montserrat:wght@100;300;400;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- favicon -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">

  <!-- title -->

  <title>Product preview card component</title>

  <!-- bootstrap -->

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-iYQeCzEYFbKjA/T2uDLTpkwGzCiq6soy8tYaI1GyVh/UjpbCx/TYkiZhlZB6+fzT" crossorigin="anonymous">


  <!-- css sheet -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

</head>


<body>

  <div class="small-box">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <img src="images/image-product-desktop.jpg" alt="product image" width="300px">

      </div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-6">
        <div class="text">
          <h6>PERFUME</h6>
          <h1>Gabrielle Essence Eau De Parfum</h1>
          <p> A floral, solar and voluptuous interpretation composed by Olivier Polge, Perfumer-Creator for the House of CHANEL.</p>
          <h1 class="price">$149.99</h1>
          <p class="price-tag"><s>$169.99</s></p>
          <button type="button" class="btn button" name="button"> <svg width="15" height="16"
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path
                                d="M14.383 10.388a2.397 2.397 0 0 0-1.518-2.222l1.494-5.593a.8.8 0 0 0-.144-.695.8.8 0 0 0-.631-.28H2.637L2.373.591A.8.8 0 0 0 1.598 0H0v1.598h.983l1.982 7.4a.8.8 0 0 0 .799.59h8.222a.8.8 0 0 1 0 1.599H1.598a.8.8 0 1 0 0 1.598h.943a2.397 2.397 0 1 0 4.507 0h1.885a2.397 2.397 0 1 0 4.331-.376 2.397 2.397 0 0 0 1.12-2.021ZM11.26 7.99H4.395L3.068 3.196h9.477L11.26 7.991Zm-6.465 6.392a.8.8 0 1 1 0-1.598.8.8 0 0 1 0 1.598Zm6.393 0a.8.8 0 1 1 0-1.598.8.8 0 0 1 0 1.598Z"
                                fill="#FFF" />
                        </svg>
                        <b>Add to Cart</b></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-u1OknCvxWvY5kfmNBILK2hRnQC3Pr17a+RTT6rIHI7NnikvbZlHgTPOOmMi466C8" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```